Reference Flask variable (base64 string) in all Blueprint templates?
I have a Flask app with blueprints. I have a function that fetches a user's profile image and returns it as a base64 string of text (too big to store in session). I use this in the html template navbar to show the user's profile image.
I'm having difficulty sharing this image value across all html templates. I could not get context_processor method to work as it seemed to call the function immediately, versus when I call the function specifically after they've logged in.
My function:
def get_user_photo():
    # retrieves logged in user's profile picture
    try:
        sql = """
        SELECT picture_data FROM ps_image WHERE emplid = %s
        """

        db = Database()

        res = db.execute_select_ps(sql, params=[session["user_emplid"]])
        if "status" in res and res["status"] == "success":
            if "data" in res and len(res["data"]) > 0:
                images = res["data"]

                for img in images:
                    return img["picture_data"]
            else:
                logging.error(
                    f"No user photo found for {session['user_name']} [{session['user_emplid']}]: {res['status']}"
                )
                return "none"
        else:
            logging.error(
                f"Error getting user photo for {session['user_name']} [{session['user_emplid']}]: {res['status']}"
            )
            return "none"
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error getting user photo for - {}".format(repr(e)))
        return "none"

And this is where I call that function after the user has logged in:
@page_blueprint.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def landing_page(url_params=None):
    # debug session data
    for k, v in session.items():
        logging.debug(f"-> {k}: {v}")

    if "logged_in" not in session:
        return redirect(url_for("page_blueprint.login_page"))

    user_photo = get_user_photo()
    
    #
    # how can i now pass user_photo to all blueprints/templates to use?
    #

    if "sso" in request.args and request.args.get("sso") != "":
        # Take user to main home page
        return render_template("/index.html", sso=request.args.get("sso"))
    else:
        # Take user to main home page
        return render_template("/index.html")

If I do:
return render_template("/index.html", img=user_photo)

It works on that index.html page, but is only available in that one route. Not sure how to be able to reference that "img" in the other Blueprints/template html files once it's been retrieved.

you could save the image's data to disk, and add the (unique) filename to user's session. Create a job to cleanup those "cache" files periodically. Maybe you should redesign your app to have the user's photo in DB and on disk as well (with filename equal to the user's id), so you can access it from disk directly
